# Is there a way to mimic "click and drag" using the keyboard?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, mouse, xdotool

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 on an old 2008 MacBook.  My trackpad had an unfortunate accident (prolonged exposure to condensation) and no longer recognizes the "drag" portion when I'm trying to click and drag.  Other than that it works fine.  It lets me move the mouse, click, or scroll pages with no problems but for some reason if I try to drag it just moves the mouse without invoking "drag" functionality.

Is there a way to set up a hot key so if I click and hold down Shift, for example, then the computer will treat further mouse movements like a click and drag?

Comment: You can simply Strg+X and Strg+V

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Using xdotool

Not really convenient, but possible: with `xdotool`, you can simulate mouse- and keyboard events:

1. Install `xdotool`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Now you need to add two keyboard shortcuts; one to simulate pressing the left mouse button, and one to release it:

   Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   xdotool mousedown 1
   ```

   to (e.g.) <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

   and

   ```
   xdotool mouseup 1
   ```

   to (e.g.) <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

Now you can *drag* by placing the cursor on the item, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>, move the item and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to "drop" the item.